# BigQuery returning null for sub-query

Tags: mysql, subquery, google-bigquery

**What's the problem?**

My sub-query is returning NULL.

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm working with a table like the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|        url          |  page_path_1  |  page_path_2  |  filter  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  e.com/test1/test2/  |     test1     |     test2    |   foo    |
|  e.com/test1/test2/  |     test1     |     test2    |   bar    |
|  e.com/test2/test3/  |     test2     |     test3    |   foo    |
```

I want to return 20 example urls for each of the top 20 directories combinations sorted by descending foo.

**What is my current query?**

```
SELECT
  url
FROM 
  [table.data_analysis],
  (
      SELECT
        page_path_1 as pp1, page_path_2 as pp2, count(page_path_1) as count, filter
      FROM
        [table.data_analysis]
      WHERE
       filter = foo
      GROUP BY pp1, pp2, filter
      ORDER BY count desc
      LIMIT 20
    ) AS sub_query
WHERE
  filter = foo and
  page_path_1 = pp1 and
  page_path_2 = pp2
LIMIT 20
```

`sub_query` returns valid directories if you run it by itself:

```
Row  |   pp1   |  pp2    |   count  |  filter  |
-----------------------------------------------
1    |  test1  |  test2  |    1     |   foo
1    |  test2  |  test3  |    1     |   foo
```

But when you use it as an actual subquery and take a look at pp1 & pp2:

```
SELECT
  pp1, pp2
FROM 
  [table.data_analysis],
  (
      SELECT
        page_path_1 as pp1, page_path_2 as pp2, count(page_path_1) as count, filter
      FROM
        [table.data_analysis]
      WHERE
       filter = foo
      GROUP BY pp1, pp2, filter
      ORDER BY count desc
      LIMIT 20
    ) AS sub_query
WHERE
  filter = foo
LIMIT 20
```

It's returning null.

```
Row  |  pp1  |   pp2     
----------------------
1    |  null |   null
2    |  null |   null
3    |  null |   null
```

I'm completely stumped. How am I using this wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

> How am I using this wrongly?

Hope below simplified example gives you idea what is wrong here

```
SELECT filter, pp1, pp2
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, filter
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 21 AS b, 'foo' AS filter),
    (SELECT 2 AS a, 22 AS b, 'foo' AS filter),
    (SELECT 3 AS a, 23 AS b, 'foo1' AS filter),
    (SELECT 4 AS a, 24 AS b, 'foo1' AS filter),
    (SELECT 5 AS a, 25 AS b, 'foo' AS filter)
  ), (
  SELECT pp1, pp2, filter
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS pp1, 21 AS pp2, 'foo' AS filter),
    (SELECT 2 AS pp1, 22 AS pp2, 'foo1' AS filter),
    (SELECT 3 AS pp1, 23 AS pp2, 'foo' AS filter),
    (SELECT 4 AS pp1, 24 AS pp2, 'foo' AS filter),
  )
WHERE filter = 'foo'
LIMIT 2
```

Result is

```
filter  pp1 pp2  
foo null    null     
foo null    null
```

Here, you are using comma style of UNION ALL of BigQuery Legacy SQL
First piece in UNION doesn't have pp1 and pp2 so that is why they come with NULLs